# Bug: Medal selection overlapped by tabs on user page

Tags: bug, design

Earned a new badge today on Meta, but noticed that the option bar (is that the right term?) to select the next badge is partially hidden by the category tabs.

Currently on Windows 10 using Chrome v. 69.0.3497.100 (64-bit).

[image]

Comment: [Related main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316061/398063)

Comment: Yeah, that's happening all over the network. :-(

Comment: Same thing in Opera.